# Adding new column from list in dataframe But List have more values than total no of rows in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and a list

```
df=pd.read_csv('aa.csv') 

temp=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']`
```

Now my data-frame have only 3 rows. I am adding temp as a new column

```
df['temp']=pd.Series(temp)
```

But in the final df i am only getting first 3 values of temp and all others are rejected. Is there any way to add a list of larger/smaller in size as  a new column to the dataframe 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for create rows filled by missing values before created new column:

```
df = pd.read_csv('aa.csv') 

temp = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']

df = df.reindex(range(len(temp)))
df['temp'] = pd.Series(temp)
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3]})
print(df)
   A
0  1
1  2
2  3

temp = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']

df = df.reindex(range(len(temp)))
df['temp']=pd.Series(temp)
print (df)
     A temp
0  1.0    1
1  2.0    2
2  3.0    3
3  NaN    4
4  NaN    5
5  NaN    6
6  NaN    7
```

Or use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with `Series` with specify name for new column name:

```
s = pd.Series(temp, name='temp')

df = pd.concat([df, s], axis=1)
```

Similar:

```
s = pd.Series(temp)
df = pd.concat([df, s.rename('temp')], axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df)
     A temp
0  1.0    1
1  2.0    2
2  3.0    3
3  NaN    4
4  NaN    5
5  NaN    6
6  NaN    7
```